# Limit one user per IP in Drupal 6.22

Tags: 7, users

Recently I found that multiple accounts are being created in my Drupal 6.22 website by someone from a particular IP. Is someone aware of any modules to limit the user to create only one account per ip?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it seems spammy, then maybe use Drupal to block the IP address (settings.php or admin) but if it's only a few and they look okay and genuine it could be users from the same college or company behind a proxy server.

If it you still want to block someone you could add an additional validate function to the user registration form and include an IP check in there.